# SPF2010: Parser error on all client pages after KB2910904

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, cumulative-update, small-business-server

Dealing with an installation of SharePoint Foundation 2010 (14.0.7143.5000) that was included with Small Business Server 2011.

Everything worked fine yesterday, until the latest cumulative update (KB2910904) was successfully installed overnight by Windows Update.  Now, all SharePoint sites and pages come back with the error below.

I tried running `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait`, which completed successfully but didn't fix the problem.  (EDIT: doing that took down Central Administration as well)

As a test, I also tried restoring the pre-update web.config files, but that did nothing.

The Windows logs are equally unhelpful, logging one warning (1310) whenever I try to load a page in my browser.

---

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *Parser Error*

**Description:** An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.   Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
            

             **Parser Error Message:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

            **Source Error:** 

            
               
                  
                      

`[No relevant source lines]`

                  
               
            

            

             **Source File:**  none    **Line:**  1
            

            

            **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483

---

UPDATE:  I tried resetting the farm account password, but still no dice.  I was able to log in with SQL Server Management Studio as the farm account, but I still get blood in the logs (3760).  [This guy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84656/critical-error-in-event-log-after-installation-login-failed-for-user) was having the same issue as me, but didn't get anywhere either.

Comment: What errors are you getting in ULS Viewer? Are you able to pull up Central Admin? Any errors shown there?

Comment: No, now Central Admin is giving me the same Parser Error message.  The only things I can find in the ULS Viewer that look like errors are "The application domain /LM/W3SVC/2102256223/ROOT-23-130681524180405292 is unloading and going to be recycled," and then "Shutdown Reason: Initialization Error  HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown HostingEnvironment caused shutdown."

Comment: What does ULS Viewer say? Check for Urgent errors. They should be highlighted in red.

Comment: Nothing is Urgent.  Everything I see is either High or Medium.  I'm looking at older logs right now to see if there was anything logged during the update last night.

Comment: Good idea. You may just need to re-install.

Comment: Best I can tell, the farm account became unable to log on to SQL Server during the update.  I may try running that update again.

Comment: You may need to check that the farm account has access to the content database and central admin database.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!  Months ago, I applied [a custom patch to the compat.browser files to support Safari 8 and iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936427/aspmenu-in-safari-7-1-not-rendering-properly-in-sharepoint-2010).  Despite this update not touching that browser file, the change still broke it.

I reverted to the previous compat.browser file (dated 2/11/2014) for each site, and SharePoint came back to life.   Then, I added [this different patch](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2014/10/did-safari-or-ios-8-break-your-sharepoint-2010-site/) to make Safari 8 happy.